# Enviar imagen con Ajax

Tags: ajax

Como puedo enviar una imagen a través de ajax?

El código que tengo es este y por ahora solo envía texto, como podría coger la imagen de un `<input type="file" id="foto"/>` y enviarla?

Mi código:

```
function updateProfile(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var lastname = $("#lastname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    $("#form-updateProfile").submit(function(){
        var profileData = {
            name : name,
            lastname : lastname,
            email : email,
            phone : phone
        }
        $.post('php/db_updateProfile.php', profileData, returnValues);
        return false;
    });
    function returnValues(recievedData){
        console.log(recievedData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

intenta agregar **enctype="multipart/form-data"** en el elemento **form** html. Creo que te seria mas facil si lo serializas de la siguiente manera ya que usas jquery: 
`$('form').serialize();` con eso te serializa todo el formulario con los valores.

El html se vería así:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="miImagen">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

El JavaScript seria lo siguiente:

```
 $("#form").on('submit',function(){
      $.post('php/db_updateProfile.php', $('#form').serialize(), returnValues);
 });
```

Seguí con tu código para darte un ejemplo...

Comment: El metodo que indicas para la el envio de datos e imagen  es correcta pero seria bueno que coloques un poco de codigo de ejemplo ya que puede que que el que hizo la pregunta no te haya entendido.

Comment: Tienes razón @Shassain, ahora lo edito.